# copy dependencies in a spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I have spring boot application where during maven install, I want it to create a jar and copy the dependencies into a lib folder. I am trying to use these two maven plugins that are working fine in other maven projects but doesn't work in a spring boot application.

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
           <useDefaultManifestFile>true</useDefaultManifestFile>
           <archive>
              <manifest>
                 <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                 <mainClass>xxx.Main</mainClass>
                 <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
              </manifest>
           </archive>
        </configuration>
     </plugin>
     <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
           <execution>
              <phase>install</phase>
              <goals>
                 <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
              </goals>
              <configuration>
                 <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
              </configuration>
           </execution>
        </executions>
     </plugin>
```

What is happening is that the jar gets created even if the maven-jar-plugin is omitted. And it doesn't do anything with the maven-dependency-plugin. So it pretty much ignores both these plugins.

Comment: Have you tried  - https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-maven-plugin.html

Comment: @Anton: I had not seen that. Seems like that is what I was looking for. I will try it out. Thank you!

Comment: Okay I tried that. It still doesn't show me how to copy dependencies to an external folder.

Comment: Why do you want the dependencies into an external folder?! Your jar should contain all you need so you don't need to mess around with additional folders.

Comment: There are other applications built by other teams, which share a lot of these common jars (Hibernate, spring and so on). If I have them in an external folder, there is an option of being able to share these dependencies in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I put the Spring Boot plugin after copy-dependencies and work fine!

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
</plugin>
```

*Notes:* I clean Maven repository to work!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try Spring boot + Gradle:
[Spring boot Gradle](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-gradle-plugin.html)

In build.gradle file, you can customize the build process and copy your dependencies into lib folder by using gradle copy method.